# Disable and / or keywords substitution in Python mode in Emacs 25.1

Tags: python, fonts

How can I disable `and` / `or` keywords substitution in Python mode in Emacs 25.1?

Cygwin `emacs-w32` can't find appropriate fonts in Windows (for `∧` and `∨`)...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
(defun my/python-mode-hook ()
  (when (eq window-system 'w32)
    (setq prettify-symbols-alist nil)))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my/python-mode-hook)
```

So I do:

```
(defun my/python-mode-hook ()
  (when (and (eq window-system 'w32) (fboundp 'prettify-symbols-mode))
    (prettify-symbols-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my/python-mode-hook)
```

The problem because I have:

```
(global-prettify-symbols-mode 1)
```

that I set 2 years ago...